# Calling private members of another Function - Issues with Arrays and Types

Tags: c++, arrays, class, private

I'm having trouble with C++ calling elements of an *array* of type *class*. 
Here is a sample of my code;

```
//village.h
class village
{
    public:
        class Human
        {
            public:
                void setGender(std::string g);
                std::string getGender();
            private:
                std::string gender;
        };

        class World
        {
            public:
                void join(Human c, int i);
            private:
                Human humanArray[20];
        };

//village.cpp
void village::World::join(Human c, int i)
{
    humanArray[i] = c;
    cout << humanArray[i].gender << endl;
    cout << c.getGender() << endl;
}

//main.cpp

village::Human h;
village::World world

h.setGender("Male");
world.join(c, 1);
```

The problem I'm having is, I'm getting error in the line;

```
cout << humanArray[i].gender << endl;
```

saying

> 'gender' is private.

However, didn't I declare the array of type Human? And I'm not getting error when adding so I assume this works ok. But when I try and call an element, I'm getting error. I can't change the variables from private to public.

Comment: You're aware of what "private" means, right?  The very point of it is that it's not accessible outside the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to

```
cout << humanArray[i].getGender() << endl;
```

**Technical background on why this works:**

The member variable `gender` is declared *private* in the `Human` class, thus other classes (and instances of them) cannot access it (without special permission).  The member functions `Human::getGender()` and `Human::setGender()` are declared *public*, so they can be accessed on instances (objects) of class `Human`.

Because a member function can access *private* members (variables and functions) of the class it belongs to, `Human::getGender()` (also true for `Human::setGender()`) can access the *private* `gender` member variable of class `Human`.

The function `join()` is a member of class `World`, which is distinct from class `Human`, thus it has access to *public* members only (i.e. has access to `Human::getGender()`, but not to `Human::gender`)

Accessing the elements of the array has nothing to do with the above.  All elements of an array can be accessed by code that has visibility/access to the array (think of the elements as if they were *public* within the array, with no way to set them *private*)

Answer (score 1):

You should use your accessor method getGender()

```
cout << humanArray[i].getGender()<< endl;
```

hummanArray is a member of `World` and so any instances of the class `World` can access that.

gender is a member of the `Human` class and therefore cannot be directly accessed by member functions of the `World` class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the member variable `gender` is indeed declared private, so you cannot access it from the World class. When you say `humanArray[i].gender` you get a Human and then try to access its gender member (which is private). Use `humanArray[i].getGender()` instead.